# Software center errors and doesn't update any more

Tags: software-center, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download package files error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/failed-to-download-package-files-error)

My software center was working when I first downloaded with the new and clean installation of the OS,  but now its not working now.

I have tried the `sudo apt-get update` also with no luck. I would like to download some things from the software center but its asking me to check my internet connection, then it gives me a error code of things it needs to download software from a untrusted source and I have the source list ticked.

I need to know what to do on my end so that I can get it working again or is this something I need to wait for a fix?

Comment: Please open a terminal, put in `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and post the output here in code tags. That way it provides a more exact description of your problem.

Comment: Please provide screenshots so that we can understand it even better. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Requires installation of untrusted packages The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources. thats what the box tells me what do i do to get it back running properly and i took a screen shot but dont know how to upload it

Comment: At the end of the update i get these error's................. W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, iv tried instead of sudo apt-get update i typed in gksudo apt-get update, it will prompt for ur password, will fetch and download stuff, at the end i got:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then I re-ran the update software it worked ( i have the souce code in the settings ticked)

dont ask me how or why its been 1 month since iv been using ubuntu :P just got lucky!