# How do I fix a "Failed to download package files" error?

Tags: updates, update-manager

After I installed Ubuntu , I cannot update any software with the error message "failed to download package files". After having googled, I have tried:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. changed to another sources

But I still got the same error message. And there is no problem with internet connection as i can connect to internet using Firefox in Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem after upgradin from 13.10 to 14.04. It was fixed by running:

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf & sudo apt-get update

See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=863742&s=98fd353f9d4215b805db121e7dbd2dd6&p=5415838#post5415838

Comment: This is frustrating because the first time it happened I was watching the activity and I noticed a few packages had errors.  But on subsequent times everything is cached so it pops up the error almost immediately without giving me any time to examine which packages actually failed!

Answer (score 88):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `software-properties-gtk`.

Change the download location to **Main Server** or another server close to the country you live in and try to `sudo apt-get update` again.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Run the following commands (saves a backup of the old lists and creates a new lists folder) and the BADSIG error does not occur:

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: in case it still doesn't work try: [this command](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/14024/clean-apt-get-and-gpg-cache-and-keys)

Answer (score 8):

There's a [Package Manager Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure) that usually solves this sort of problem. Perform steps 1-4 of that procedure. (Step 1, which is sometimes enough, is what [Bruno Pereira](https://askubuntu.com/users/25863/bruno-pereira) has posted--in better detail--in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/82834/22949). If step 1 isn't enough, continue with the other steps.)

If that doesn't solve the problem, then please select all the text in the Terminal (`Edit` > `Select All`), copy it to the clipboard (`Edit` > `Copy`), and edit your question to include it (you'll want to make it a blockquote so that the formatting doesn't get messed up). This will then provide highly useful information for solving the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that single enabled repository failing to update will cause this message. In my case, it was dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic - I unchecked and no longer get error messages.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm on Linux Mint, which is Ubuntu at its base (which is Debian at its base), 
anyway, very probably this will work...

"Open Software Sources from the menu, 
click the Maintenance button 
and there click the Fix MergeList Issue button."

-- said **kc1di** at the [Linux Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=256426&p=1764531#p1764531)

please don't thank me for this, I'm only sharing the solution that worked like charm for me just a minute ago... (2020, 02 18)