# Error when installing VLC

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-netbook, vlc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download package files error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/failed-to-download-package-files-error)

**My Laptop model:** Dell N4110

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and tried to install vlc music player but it shows alert "Failed to download repository information, check your Internet connection ". But Internet is connected. what should I do????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/vlc/1.1.11-2build2

Choose the correct processor architecture in the Builds links list. That will install, but you have got to solve that problem. Try to change the server: Open 'Software Sources' and in 'Download from:', select 'Other', and then 'Choose the best one'. Hope is helps...