# Unable to download packages from Ubuntu Software Center - "Check Your Internet Connection"

Tags: package-management, internet, downloads, connection

Whenever I try to install any package, I get the error "Unable to Download Packages", "Check your Internet connection". But the strange part is that I can use synaptic to download and install the same packages.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to download package files error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/failed-to-download-package-files-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Software Center > Edit > Software Sources.. > then from Ubuntu Software (tab) > (Check  ) Download From > { Change the Server  }

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked which server you are downloading from ? Try switching to main, i just recently had the same problem with the canadian server.

Comment: im on my phone  when i get to a pc i can tell you how to change/check it

Comment: The main server didn't work, it wasn't even connecting to the repositiory. But thanks, the next reply helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  It started after I switched from a wireless card to a standard ethernet connection.   After I switched to ethernet, my internet browser (Chrome) and E-mail (Thunderbird) worked fine, but I was getting the same software update issues.

If you look in the upper right hand edge of the screen, there is a up-arrow/down-arrow symbol near the blutooth and speaker volume symbols.  This is the network manager.

It you right-click on it with a mouse you should see a list of your wired and wireless connections. After I switched, Network Manager had a message at the top that said something to the effect of "Ethernet connection wired device not managed".

I found the article: [network manager says "device not managed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)

But to summarize, I used the following Command Line commands to make it work:

To do this - in a terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Change the line

```
managed=false
```

to

```
managed=true
```

Save (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> and enter)

Stop and start network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And it should work (it worked for me).