# Problems in updating ubuntu 12.04

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu Software Center not working - “Check Your Internet Connection”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100057/ubuntu-software-center-not-working-check-your-internet-connection)

Installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I got this problem:

1. No install option in any software in software centre
2. Can't install any tar.gz or any program
3. Can't update through terminal
4. Can't download any update , its says check ur network connection but my internet is working at the same time.

Comment: This is a laundry list, not a question.  You need to ask a specific question, and provide background details.

Answer (score 0):

You try to do in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you get an error, please paste it on another comment to this message.