# Using ubuntu software center

Tags: 14.04

when i try to install a program from Ubuntu software center it shows an error to "check your Internet connection."
I'm sure that my laptop is connected to Internet as i can load any page in Firefox.
what can i do?

Comment: posible duplicate:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/100057/ubuntu-software-center-not-working-check-your-internet-connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for using Ubuntu, is this is a fresh installation of Ubuntu open up a terminal by hiting Ctrl+Alt_T then type`sudo apt-get update` check for any errors given to you, if no errors, re-open the software center and try again.

Alternatively, you may also try installing software via terminal by a simply `sudo apt-get install *package_name*` This of-course if you feel comfortable working with the terminal. Good luck and ask again if you have no success.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

this means that one or more of the repositories that you have setup are not valid/offline/not in use

You can check to see what repositories you are set up to use by checking what "software sources" are available to your system by checking the repository list.....

open Synaptic Package Manager go to settings click on repositories

here you can look at and configure all the software sources - or only use trusted.. etc...

to check the list of servers or repositories your are set up to use.... check the tab that says "other software" you will see a more complete list of the servers your computer is set to receive from...