# Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 11.10, gnome

When I try to install any application without the support of Canonical, the software center said that "You have a problems with internet connection" or "Requires installation of untrusted packages" and does not let me to install

For this reason, I am afraid to reinstall the system, because after reinstalling, I would not be able to download the necessary application to me

Please help me as soon as possible!!!

Comment: Try this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/82834/25798) and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [bug in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/705988) related to your error. It is not solved yet, but there is a workaround to solve your problem. Please, remember to mark this bug as affecting you in order to fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: Wnen you finaly fix it?

Comment: I'm not in the bug team, I'm just a user like you.. :)