# update problem 11.10

Tags: 11.10, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a “Failed to download package files” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/how-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-download-package-files-error)

Whenever I try to install any software through Terminal or Software on my Ubuntu 11.10, I'm getting this response:
Failed to download repository information
Check your Internet connection.
please help me
,

Answer (score 0):

Check your software sources> download from> other> select best server> change the mirror to best server, let it update and retry.

[image]