# Unable to install from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download package files error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/failed-to-download-package-files-error)

Everytime I try to download something from Ubuntu Software Center it says... 
Check Your Internet Connection... 
and shows some PPA Repository error which I tried to fix but still it pop ups everytime...

Comment: Only for the PPA repo is this causing problem? Then those are invalid repo URLs. Remove them.

Answer (score 0):

In the Ubuntu Software Centre, go to the `Edit` menu and click on `Software Sources`. Then go to the "Other Software" tab, and remove the ppa's that are failing to download.

If you want to add any of the ppa's again, the best way is usually by running `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:someppa/ppa` in the terminal. You can usually find the exact `ppa:someppa/ppa` string on that PPA's launchpad page. This will ensure the PPA gets added with the right signing keys, so it should stop giving you as many warnings.