# Ubuntu Software Center: Failed to download package files?

Tags: installation, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a “Failed to download package files” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/how-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-download-package-files-error)

I am not able to download any application from Software Center, it shows me this message

```
Failed to download package files
```

neither am I able to update.

Comment: can you achive do the same task in Synaptic?

Comment: Can you post the exact error it shows.