# Software center failing to install Softwares

Tags: 12.04, software-center

My Lappy is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
There is no best server found for IIT Kharagpur servers.
Error message: 
"
**Failed to download package files**
check your internet connection.
"
but it is connected to internet.

Comment: Another mirror is glug.nith.ac.in , you should try out this. if it fails then connect any mirror outside india.

Comment: When I changed my server to glug.nith.ac.in, Entire software center is Empty.. Can't even see a single software in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Failed to download package files" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/how-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-download-package-files-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try with some other server . 
you can set default server Nothing but main server . 
don't worry about server issues because they are temporary. they might be down for maintenance .

you can try again after some time .

Comment: When I change my Software source to any other mirror other than 'Universal' it is becoming empty.. I can;t see a single software in it

Comment: I am not understanding your comment , sorry. could you place in image of that here .