# Problems installing adobe flash player?

Tags: flash, dell-mini-9

Whenever I try installing something I get a error. In a **terminal** I always get some error. In the **Software Center** fails. It tells me to check my Internet connection, even when I have an Ethernet cable attached to the WI-FI router.

When I try to download with the browser, opening the with the Archive Manager or saving it happens the same. I've even tried to use Flash-Aid. There seems to be a problem with my proxy or something.

I somehow managed to install Adobe Reader but I don't actually know how. I've read step by step guides but they use computer jargon that I can't understand.

Comment: If your internet connection works fine then you should try the answer provided in this http://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/how-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-download-package-files-error

Answer (score 1):

It's Definitely your Proxy. Proxy connections are often unstable(for various reasons) and can cause many Problems. I'd recommend only using the Proxy when you have to. For instance try turning off the Proxy and then install Adobe Flash. Since the Repos don't use region blocks you should be able to download and install anywhere in the world. Only if there are some really strange restrictions on your ISP would you not be able to install software on Ubuntu over the net.

After you're done installing whatever else you need you can turn the proxy back on and get on with your Web surfing.

I'd also recommend installing a Download Manager like DownThemAll for use while on a Proxy. A Download Manager can make multiple connections to a source to speed up downloads and automatically reconnect if a connection error occurs. Some (like DownThemAll) include Hash mechanisms so you can input the Download's Hash for the Manager to check with to make sure everything downloaded all right.

Comment: Not sure how to turn off the Proxy,but I have installed DownThemAll in Firefox. I have tried downloading Adobe Flash Player again - I wanted to try and open it with DownThemAll, but whenever I try downloading, it just asks me what program I want to open it with, and then I can't find DownThemAll.

Comment: I don't see how you're using a proxy that you didn't setup, but you might want to look into it. Make sure you restart Firefox after installing DownThemAll. It should now appear in the Download dialogue or when you right click a Download link. Make sure you have "Always Ask me Where to Save Files" selected in the Firefox settings.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using a proxy internet connection, I'm using a network adapter. I meant that in 'Software Sources', I have set the 'download from', in 'Ubuntu Software' to a web address? I think there's a problem with that, as in Terminal when I try to install anything, it outputs the address and then 'Something wicked happened' Afterwards, it says something about 'UR_PROXY' so I got confused and thought it was something to do with that. I actually get my internet from the wifi box in my house and I use a wireless adapter.

Comment: If that's the case try going into Software Sources and change "Download From:" to "Server for [Your Country]" If that option is no longer there select "Other" and click the "Best Server" button.

Comment: I have done the 'best match test' before and I had set it to 'best match' before too.

Comment: @Louis Then just choose another server in your Country(or near it) and see if that works. Sometimes the "Best" choice isn't the right choice.

Comment: I've tried a few, always comes up with 'Failed to download repository information' and 'check your internet connection'. One of them almost loaded completely before coming up with this message.

Comment: @Louis Try a distant one then. Maybe one in a Country like the US or UK will work better.

Comment: I'm in the UK at the moment, and I've tried most of those ones, but I'll try some US ones.

Comment: Hasn't worked with any of those ones - I think it's a problem with Ubuntu or the laptop