# Error Message when trying to check for updates

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a “Failed to download package files” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/how-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-download-package-files-error)

I get the following error message whenever I try to check for updates:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/precise-getdeb/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/precise-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/precise-getdeb/apps/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Don't know what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The server `archive.getdeb.net` is not reachable at the moment. If that is a PPA deselect it, if it is your general source select a different server - just for testing "Main Server" is recommended.