# I am unable to update ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Says check internet connection

Tags: 12.04, software-sources, software-updater

I cannot install my updates. I used the following information [How do I fix a "Failed to download package files" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/how-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-download-package-files-error) but it didn't work.

In the software sources window under the "ubuntu software" tab everything except the source code is checked.
Under the "other software" tab I have Canonical Partners and Canonical Partners (Source code) and that's all.

When i try to update my software it says:

Failed to download repository information

Check your Internet connection.

I have ubuntu 12.04LTS

please help

Comment: can you ping Google?  `ping -c 5 www.google.com`

Comment: Try to upgrade your system via the terminal:
<code>sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade</code>
Please copy the output, then we will be smarter :)
Anyway, do you have a proper internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. Software Updater barely tries and then gives up saying to check my internet connection.

It works fine when I do it from the terminal, as lukibeni suggested.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Updating from the terminal I get consistent 100kB/s down, which isn't broadband speeds, but it clearly works just fine, Software Updater. At least for some subset of users, the software updater tool is mostly broken.

I see another answer (https://askubuntu.com/questions/276191/software-updater-wont-update-says-to-check-internet-ubuntu-12-10?rq=1) about going into the software sources options and changing the server you get updates from. That didn't work for me.