# Can not download VLC using Ubuntu Sofware Center

Tags: software-center, vlc

I am trying to install VLC from Ubuntu Software Center on Ubuntu 14.04. It always says that it failed to download the package and that I have to check my internet connection.
I have no problem with my internet connection. Just before I tried to install VLC, I had installed other packages.
I tried then " sudo apt-get update " and "sudo apt-get install --fix-missing", but the problem is sitill unsolved.
What is the problem, and what are the possible solutions?

Comment: there is a possiblity that at least one ppa might be broken, can you post the output of `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: Fetched 2,674 kB in 36s (72.5 kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: try this answer it should work http://askubuntu.com/a/70636/294611

Comment: this didn't work too. I installed many other packages. Only VLC installation failed!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is opening Terminal and using the command

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

If that fails, update your question with the exact wording of any error message you receive.  Also useful would be your particular version of linux (we could be looking at an issue with the repositories.  For example, if you are using an older version you would need to update yours with the archived ones...or upgrade to a supported version of linux.  This 'expiration' of given repositories happens fairly quickly.  I once had one expire on me in the middle of an apt-get command....that was a bit messy but recoverable.).

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Using this command was not helpful, I got the following: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?.

Comment: And what happens when you use those suggested fixes?  Do they solve your issue?

Comment: they were not helpful!. No thing changed.